# Ansible ERROR! 'AnsibleUnicode' object has no attribute 'keys

Tags: ansible

I am running Ansible for the first time and I get this error:

```
root@raspberrypi:/opt/ansible# ansible-playbook -i /opt/ansible/hosts simple.yml 
ERROR! 'AnsibleUnicode' object has no attribute 'keys'
/opt/ansible/hosts:1: Expected key=value host variable assignment, got: juniper
```

Content of `simple.yml`:

```
---
- name: Verifying NETCONF
  hosts: juniper
  tasks: 
    - name: Verifying NETCONF
      wait_for: host={{ansible_ssh_host}} port=22
```

Content of `hosts`:

```
juniper ansible_connection=local juniper ansible_port=22 ansible_host=172.16.0.1 juniper_user=root juniper_passwd=Juniper.2015
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Take out the juniper before and after the ansible_connection=local

Comment: Thanks! Needed to remove only the second juniper statment!